# Difference in singleton object with parentheses and without in pattern matching?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

On using `even()` is it so that it only matches the true condition from the `unapply` and on using `even` , how does this still prints `"Is even"`

```
object even{
  def unapply(arg: Int): Boolean = (arg%2 == 0)
}
object singleDigit{
  def unapply(arg: Int): Option[Boolean] = {
    if(arg < 10) Some(true)
    else None
  }
}
val n = 9
n match {
  case even() => println("Is even")
  case singleDigit => println("is single")
  case _ => println("No property")
}
//This gives "is single" 

n match {
  case even => println("Is even")
  case singleDigit => println("is single")
  case _ => println("No property")
}
//This gives "Is even"
```

How is even case satisfied here being n=9 as an odd number ?
what is the difference between even and even() inside this pattern matching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `case even =>` is actually a *variable* pattern and is not referring to `even.unapply` as hinted by compiler warning

```
Warning:(19, 9) patterns after a variable pattern cannot match (SLS 8.1.1)
If you intended to match against object even in class A$A3, you must use backticks, like: case `even` =>
  case even => println("Is even")
       ^
```

You just happened to have given it the same name, but you could write

```
n match {
  case foo => println("Is even")
  ...
}
```

and it would still print out `Is even` because the variable pattern is in the first position.